# Wordpress Contact Form 7 tags are not replaced

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

We are using contact form 7 on a managed WP 1&1 IONOS instance (WP 5.1.1).

In the response e-mail that we get, all the form variables (tags) are not replaced. Instead of the values, we see the field names like:

[firstname] [lastname]

The email is well received, but without the actual data

Comment: You should also include the relevant parts of your form template.

Comment: I stumbled over https://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-emails-arrive-with-field-tags-instead-of-values/page/2/#post-11335871 --> according to 1&1 IONOS bugfix rollout is ongoing and should be fixed by today EOB. According to this user it is already working for him again: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/contact-form-7-emails-arrive-with-field-tags-instead-of-values/page/2/#post-11338990

Answer (score 1):

After some serious digging around, we found that this behaviour/bug was triggered by a filter called **wpcf7_posted_data**.

Furthermore, we found that a plug-in in the wordpress mu-plugin folder was causing the problem. The plugin is enforced by 1&1 IONOS, and is called "**cozy-address-book**".

Since we cannot disable this particular plug-in, we rename the whole mu-plugins folder.

After that, contact-form7 worked totally fine and the data is submitted.

We will reach out to 1&1 and will ask for a permanent solution.